# Doxygen Latex Table

Tags: fortran, latex, doxygen

I want to create a Latex table in my Doxygen documentation of Fortran code.
I have used a tabular declaration for the Latex tabular command.

The commands shown do not produce the required table, but just 
get a text version of the Latex code.

```
!> \f{tabular}{
!>   1 & 2 & 3 \\
!>   4 & 5 & 6 \\
!>   7 & 8 & 9 \\
!> \f}
```

I have tried the following code to see if things work as expected. As specified by 
the Doxygen documentation formulas or other latex elements that are not in a math 
environment can be specified using \f{environment}, where environment is the name 
of the LaTeX environment, the corresponding end command is \f}. Here is an example 
for an equation array

```
!> \f{eqnarray*}{
!>    g &=& \frac{Gm_2}{r^2} \\ 
!>      &=& \frac{(6.673 \times 10^{-11}\,\mbox{m}^3\,\mbox{kg}^{-1}\,
!>          \mbox{s}^{-2})(5.9736 \times 10^{24}\,\mbox{kg})}{(6371.01\,\mbox{km})^2} \\ 
!>      &=& 9.82066032\,\mbox{m/s}^2
!>  \f}
```

Comment: I think the first line should contain something about the layout of the table e.g. something like |r|r|r|. In the formula this would be like (as doxygen "eats" the first '}' after the package) \f{tabular}{{|l|l|l|}. Note this is only for the dot generated / LaTeX output.

Comment: Another possibility is to use the Markdown possibilities of doxygen to create tables.

Comment: The problem is that I want to have Latex formulas in the table. I have tried using `\f{tabular}{{|c|c|c|}` to no avail.

Comment: Done it, did not know the detail about the two curly brackets `{{` after `\f{tabular}`. I was doing `\f{tabular}{ccc}{` rather than `\f{tabular}{{ccc}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, solution involves using d two curly brackets after \f{tabular}.

```
\f{tabular}{{ccc}
```